# How do I view my static web files on parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a way to view the static web files that have been uploaded to parse.com by "parse deploy"/"parse develop" from my public parse folder? I see how to view the cloud code, but not the rest.

This seems like a basic feature/question, but I haven't been able to find answers in the docs or elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this.

You could report it as a bug/feature-request.